# Local changes checked in to index but not committed. Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index

Tags: git

Looking at my git log I have:

```
Local changes checked in to index but not committed
```

then on the next line

```
Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index
```

Can someone explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

Git has a staging area called the "index", where you collect stuff that goes into the next commit. You manage the index with the `git add`, `git rm`, `git mv` commands.

You have probably changed a few files, `add`ed SOME of them, so a part of your changes are staged for the next commit in the index.

To view additional changes compared to what is staged for the next commit - this is the default behaviour of `diff`

```
git diff
```

All changes - both staged and unstaged - compared to last commit

```
git diff HEAD
```

Changes staged for next commit

```
git diff --cached HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because that there are **some untracked files (tmp files that some editors leave behind)** which is not committed.

Ex)

```
me@mydev:/var/www/webworks/app$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

conf/config.php~

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

if you remove the temp file which is not commited/tracked everything will be fine.

```
me@mydev:/var/www/webworks/app$ rm ./conf/config.php~ 
me@mydev:/var/www/webworks/app$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem,

I used to use `gitk --all` directly to see the changes (no need to commit first),

now I have to use `git gui` to help